# Firebase Security Rules: All Read Single Property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am setting up a Firebase database for a booking process. Every user can read and write their own bookings. Rules for this below:

```
"bookings": {
        //user can only read/write their bookings
        "$user": {
          ".read": "auth.uid === $user",
          ".write": "auth.uid === $user",
        }
      }
```

When a user goes to make a booking, they need to see the unavailable dates in a calendar. So they technically need to be able to read the arrival and departure properties of a booking node, so the app can populate the calendar with existing bookings and mark dates unavailable.

Of course, while doing this, all other booking information must stay private and only accessible by the user who made it. Perhaps trying to read the single property is not the correct solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think a more appropriate data structure could be this:

```
{
  "bookings": {
    "rooms": {
      "room1": {
        "booking1": {
          "fromDate": timestamp,
          "toDate": timestamp,
          "privateData": {
            "userID": "user1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "users": {
    "user1": {
      "name": "Devid"
      "bookings": {
        "room1": {
          "booking1": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So that your security rules can allow any user to only read `fromDate` and `toDate`

```
"bookings": {
  //user can only read/write their bookings
  "$roomID": {
    "$bookingID": {
      "fromDate": {  
        ".read": "auth.uid !== null",
        ".write": "newData().userID === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Josh, does this helps? :)